# Error hosting asp.net application Can't load type

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting, config

i have created a simple asp.net application which runs fine locally.

I have uploaded the application to my website and ran through as error saying

> " It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   appliction."

this error was due to the fact that the subfolder i uploaded my application to is not configured as an application in the webserver (IIS ? maybe) and therefore i can't have multiple config files.

i solved this issue by moving some entries from the subfolder config file to the root config file.

HOWEVER, THIS HAS INTRODUCED ANOTHER ERROR.

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'CvForm._Default'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"
>   MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Line 2:
>   CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CvForm._Default" %> Line 3:
>
> Source File: /CvForm/Default.aspx    Line: 1
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3625;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3634

I have been trying for the last 4-5 hrs to solve this issue with no luck.

I will appreciate someone pointing me to a way to solve this issue. 
( im sure im doing something the wrong way.. I'm new to asp.net world! ).

Kindest Regards,
Aamran

Comment: I have found the problem! ..

since i have moved my webconfig to the root folder now my application expects DLL files to be in the bin folder of the root and no the subfolder.

All i had to was to copy all content from the subfolder's bin to the root's bin.

Sorry for bothering you with a tedious mistake.

(Though, hopefully some1 will benefit from this! ).

Answer (score 1):

if your web site does not run on the remote server, be sure you have deploye all the project dependency. Take a look at the project references and be sure you deployed all the dll.